# Concentration with or without replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have a finite set of $N$ independent, identically distributed samples, $X_1,\dots,X_N$. If I sample $n<N$ of them without replacement as samples $x_i^{(\text{no replace})} $, and $n$ with replacement as $x_i^{(\text{replace})}$, is the following true?
$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{(\text{no replace})} -n\mathbb{E}[X]>a\right)\leq P\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{(\text{replace})} -n\mathbb{E}[X]>a\right)$$
where $a>0$.

Intuitively, I think this should be true, since if there are large values in the set, in the without replacement case, these large values can be drawn only once, whereas in the other case, they might get drawn more often. However, I was not able to make this more substantial.
I thought of using a coupling between the with and the without replacement case, but for me, this did not work.

Comment: May be it would be helpful to consider the variance of $Y_n=n\cdot \overline X$ in both cases.

Comment: I think it is indeed possible to show that the variance of $\sum_i x_i^{\text{(replace)}}$ is bigger than the variance of $\sum_i x_i^{\text{(no replace)}}$, but I think you need more than that to show the statement.